# cq5 can't create servlet resource

Tags: java, servlets, osgi, aem, sling

I create a servlet in my CQ5 application:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.sling.SlingServlet;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet;

@SlingServlet(
        label = "Example Servlet",
        paths = {"/bin/project/signin"},
        methods = {"GET"},
        extensions = {"html"},
        metatype = false
)
public class SignInServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 796802690004962223L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request,
            SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
            IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(SlingHttpServletRequest request,
            SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
            IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.getOutputStream().print("Sigin Servlet");
    }
}
```

i try to call it via rest-client but it return:

```
No resource found for url: http://localhost:4502/bin/project/signin
```

I also open Sling Resource Resolver at Felix side to test if it available. But i received:

```
NonExistingResource, path=/bin/project/signin
```

`/bin/` already config in Apache Sling Servlet/Script Resolver and Error Handler at Fellix

Answer (score 2):

In the `@SlingServlet` annotation you've declared that this servlet supports only requests with `.html` extension, so you should hit following URL:

```
http://localhost:4502/bin/project/signin.html
```

If you don't want to use the extension, remove appropriate parameter from the servlet annotation.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to help debug this type of situation —

1. The [**ServletResolver**](http://your-cq-instance.example.com:4502/system/console/servletresolver) will allow you to check which Servlet a given GET or POST request will resolve against.
2. If you find the request you made that generated the 404 in the **[Recent Requests](http://your-cq-instance.example.com:4502/system/console/requests)** tab, it should tell you exactly what properties it has found by Sling when trying to resolve it.

E.g. in your case, I presume the 404 is giving something like:

```
LOG Resource Path Info: SlingRequestPathInfo: \
path='/bin/project/signin', \
selectorString='null', \
extension='null', \
suffix='null'
```

Comparing this against the settings in your annotation, there's an **extension='null'** here that wouldn't match against your servlet — which is binding only against a **'html'** extension, as [Tomek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699002/1474421) rightly says above.